# Find the derivative with respect to $x$ of $y=\log_4 (x^3)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I got $\frac{3x^2}{x^3(\ln 4)}$.  Then $x$ cancels and left with $\frac{3}{x \ln4}$ ? That felt too easy so I'm sure its wrong. Or am I actually correct on this one?

Comment: Just because it's easy, it doesn't mean that is wrong. But I know that feeling bro, you're not alone. :D

Answer (score 2):

You did it correctly.  Another way of doing it is to use the rules for logarithms, so
$$
\log_4(x^3) = 3 \log_4(x) = \frac{3}{\ln 4} \ln x
$$
So the derivative is clearly $\frac{3}{\ln 4} \cdot \frac1x$.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to notice $4^{y} = x^{3}$, differentiating implicitly:

$$4^{y}\ln{(4)}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 3x^{2}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{3x^{2}}{4^{y}\ln{(4)}} = \frac{3x^{2}}{x^{3}\ln{(4)}} = \frac{3}{x\ln{(4)}}$$